Trying to link allauth provider
so, I have everything related to allauth (a django oauth provider) connected
and then in my login template I have the following href:
<a href="{% provider_login_url 'google' process='connect' %}" style="text-decoration: none;"...
the following error arise:

MultipleObjectsReturned at /login/
No exception message supplied

I can't understand what is wrong with it, it's nothing to do with process='connect' although because I tried to remove it.
